# Mantener el foco en un campo de un form HTML

Tags: php, html, entrada, texto

Necesito hacer una lectura de de código de producto de manera cíclica, y que cada vez que se pulse "enter", se ejecute un script de PHP, luego devuelva el foco a la textbox, dejándolo "limpio" para una próxima entrada.. Cualquier ayuda será muy apreciada.

Comment: Cualquier código y evidencia de lo que has intentado será muy apreciado. Puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).